# How can I get field_name from the first table using relationship between two models using laravel 6?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6

I have two tables with two models and make a reactionship to can get the `field_name` from the first table :-

First Model:

```
    class KpcField extends Model
{
    public function concession(){
        return $this->hasMany(Concessions::class);
    }
}
```

Second Model :

```
 class Concessions extends Model
{
    public function kpcField(){
        return $this->belongsTo(KpcField::class);
    }
}
```

And trying to retreive the `field_name` in concession view but it showed (Trying to get property `field_name` of non-object)

Using the foreach to show the data in table :

```
@foreach ($show_concessions as $show_concession)

<td> {{ $show_concession->kpcField->field_name}} </td>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

You can Try This :

```
@foreach ($show_concessions as $show_concession)
 @foreach ($show_concession->kpcField as $item)
   <td> {{ $item->field_name}} </td>
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow .. Please add more details to your answer (Describe your answer)